# The request was forbidden. Your credentials may be denied or suspended

Tags: bing-maps

I am developing a windows application using devexpress components and Delphi but when I try to use the map component I get this error message "The request was forbidden.  Your credentials may be denied or suspended" what it means and how to fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like either you have provided a Bing Maps key into your application that has been blocked, or you didn't provide a key at all and the devexpress component might have someone else's key in it which has since been blocked. Not sure which DevExpres control you are using. If using their WPF control, here is documentation on how to use Bing Maps in it: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17459 Note that there is a BingKey parameter in the XAML example that you need to provide a value for.

DevExpress also provided some documentation on how to get a Bing Maps key here: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument10974

Additionally you can also get a Bing Maps key through Azure here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/bingmaps/mapapis/

Comment: Thanks, I am using VCL map component (Delphi) and I already created new bing key but the error message remain. I contacted devexpress support and they told me to contact provider support so they dont know !!

Comment: Try contacting the Bing Maps support team here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?tenant=ClassicCommercial&locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&pesid=13766&sd=&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wf=0&ccsid=635830587906447783